# Image as Toolbar background that hangs outside of its bounds

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I've tried using various layouts but that little bit that hangs **outside** the boundary of the rectangular toolbar doesn't work (the semi circle).

I want something like this: [image: the UBL logo (blue and white)]

How would I go about implementing this? I've something that visually looks like this but it is just an ImageView inside a relative layout. I want a proper Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Well I do now know if you want this, but I've done this example for you, hope it helps.

[image]

This is the `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineImageStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".33" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineImageEnd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".66" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/overlape_image"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guidelineImageStart"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guidelineImageEnd"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now you can play and adjust size of views.

Comment: But this is again a separate imageview. Is there no way to set a background to the toolbar so that it displays like that?

Comment: @Asim Not sure if you can do that, Is an ImageView that you put overlaping Toolabr, Toolbar has a fixed sixe, if you go through this way it will be harder than you think, that's a simple solution

Comment: Solved the problem @Asim?